# Adding a single row with a single column of one datagridview into another datagridview of multiple column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have defined a datagridview with 5 columns and another with 1 column ..what i want to do it is on the click of the button in the datagridview with the columns, the row with the single column of the other datagridview pops up..is it possible?..this is the screenshot of my datagridview..

[image]

i want to add a datarow of another datagridview with only one column..i know how to handle cellevent but what i really want is the addition of datarow with only one column..

Comment: You need to explain more of what you want and what you have tried.  _"what i want to do it is on the click on the button in the..."_ that does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
private void dgv1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
    {
        int newRow = dgv2.Rows.Add();
        dgv2.Rows[newRow].Cells[0].Value = dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Stringtext"].Value;
    }    
}
```

This should take the value from the StringText cell and place it in the first column of a newly created row in the second grid when the button in cell 4 is clicked in the first grid.

**EDIT:**

```
private void dgv1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Stringtext"].Value = dgv2.Rows[{y}].Cells[0].Value;
        }    
    }
```

This one should set the value of the cell "StringText"(which can be changed to whatever you need it to be) in dgv1 to the value of the cell in dgv2 with the rowIndex {y}.

Comment: is it possible to make the row of the dgv2 appear in the dgv1?

Comment: I guess I do not understand what you are needing to happen.  Are you trying to click the button in dgv1 and have a value from dgv2 show up next to it?

Comment: Kind of.I want a new row to appear which is of dgv2 and only contains one column..